# AdMob banner not always showing

Tags: android, admob

I have a simple hello world application which has an AdMob banner which does not always show. When I get the banner to work always, I will add the functionality to my application. I configured the banner to show test ads with the ID of my particular device. When I open my application, sometimes the test banner appears, and sometimes not, it does not matter the time I keep waiting. By the way, I always have wi-fi enabled on the phone. Why the banner does not show always? If you find it useful, sometimes when the ad does not show and I exit the app, this trace appears on my logcat:

```
05-04 11:01:44.463: W/Ads(32406): Interrupted during GADSignals creation.
05-04 11:01:44.463: W/Ads(32406): java.lang.InterruptedException
05-04 11:01:44.463: W/Ads(32406):   at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:975)
05-04 11:01:44.463: W/Ads(32406):   at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1282)
05-04 11:01:44.463: W/Ads(32406):   at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:207)
05-04 11:01:44.463: W/Ads(32406):   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.k.a(SourceFile:52)
05-04 11:01:44.463: W/Ads(32406):   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.k.a(SourceFile:98)
05-04 11:01:44.463: W/Ads(32406):   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.request.c.a(SourceFile:114)
05-04 11:01:44.463: W/Ads(32406):   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.b.run(SourceFile:19)
05-04 11:01:44.463: W/Ads(32406):   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.l.call(SourceFile:43)
05-04 11:01:44.463: W/Ads(32406):   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.n.run(SourceFile:75)
05-04 11:01:44.463: W/Ads(32406):   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:442)
05-04 11:01:44.463: W/Ads(32406):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
05-04 11:01:44.463: W/Ads(32406):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
05-04 11:01:44.463: W/Ads(32406):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
05-04 11:01:44.463: W/Ads(32406):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
05-04 11:01:44.463: W/Ads(32406):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Something that I am very afraid of is that there was a moment in which my app crashed few times, but I am unable to repeat the error. Since then, it has not crashed again, but I know it will do it and I know that the cause is the banner because before I started to use AdMob in my applications, they never crashed with an unknown cause.

This is my xml user interface:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/adsLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/test_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the class I use from the main `Activity` to manage the ads:

```
package bembibre.impossiblepuzzle;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

public class MyAdManager {
    private AdView adView;

    private String adsBlockId;
    private Context context;
    private LinearLayout adContainer;

    public MyAdManager(String adsBlockId, Activity activity, int adContainerId) {
        this.adsBlockId = adsBlockId;
        this.context = activity;
        this.adContainer = (LinearLayout) activity.findViewById(adContainerId);
    }

    private void initializeAdvertisement(AdRequest adRequest) {
        // Crear adView.
        this.adView = new AdView(this.context);
        this.adView.setAdUnitId(this.adsBlockId);
        this.adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);

        // Buscar LinearLayout suponiendo que se le ha asignado
        // el atributo android:id="@+id/mainLayout".

        // Añadirle adView.
        adContainer.addView(this.adView);

        // Cargar adView con la solicitud de anuncio.
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

    public void initializeTestAdvertisement(String deviceId) {
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(deviceId) // Mi teléfono de prueba
        .build();
        this.initializeAdvertisement(adRequest);
    }

    public void initializeRealAdvertisement() {
        // Iniciar una solicitud genérica.
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        this.initializeAdvertisement(adRequest);
    }

    public void hideAd() {
        this.adContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    public void pause() {
        if (this.adView != null) {
            this.adView.pause();
        }
    }

    public void resume() {
        if (this.adView != null) {
            this.adView.resume();
        }
    }

    public void destroy() {
        if (this.adView != null) {
            this.adView.destroy();
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, this is the only `Activity` of my app, it only loads the advertisement banner and then draws a square figure on the screen for testing purpose because this app is going to be a puzzle game:

```
package bembibre.impossiblepuzzle;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import bembibre.impossiblepuzzle.logic.models.Board;
import bembibre.impossiblepuzzle.logic.models.Square;
import bembibre.impossiblepuzzle.ui.ImpossiblePuzzleView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String ADS_ID = "ca-app-pub-****************/**********";
    private MyAdManager myAdManager;
    private Board board;

    private void loadAdvertisement() {
        this.myAdManager = new MyAdManager(MainActivity.ADS_ID, this, R.id.adsLayout);
        this.myAdManager
        .initializeTestAdvertisement("9CC8187AB379FB0C135EB41EC66D8E5D");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.loadAdvertisement();
        this.board = new Board();

        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) this.findViewById(R.id.test_layout);
        ImpossiblePuzzleView squareView = new ImpossiblePuzzleView(this);
        viewGroup.addView(squareView);
        squareView.setSquare(new Square(1, 2, 3, 2));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        this.myAdManager.resume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        this.myAdManager.pause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        this.myAdManager.destroy();
    }
}
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong. I have several apps in Google Play with this advertisement model and I don't want them to not show the ads or to crash because my users would get so angry... I don't know why the banner sometimes appears and the app works well and other times it does not appear or even the app crashes without doing anything.

EDIT: I have downloaded an example AdMob project from
https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals?hl=es#play
and error continues, so it must not be my fault. Also I think this error happens when I open consecutively several different applications with test ads on my device. It is because I have developed several applications and sometimes I test all of them consecutively. Is this related with the problem of the ads not showing?